# Silverlight application not working when deployed

Tags: silverlight, authentication, iis, deployment, nullreferenceexception

Edited:

In MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public MainPageViewModel ViewModel
        {
            set
            {
                try
                {
                    DataContext = value;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Message: {0} \r\n StackTrace: {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
                }
            }
        }
```

On Debug, no message box

Deployed:

Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
StackTrace:

```
at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SendDataToTarget()
at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SourceAcquired()
at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.System.Windows.IDataContextChangedListener.OnDataContextChanged(Object sender, DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
at at System.Windows.WeakDataContextChangedListener.MentorDataContextChanged(Object sender, DataContextChangedEventArgs e)...
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see more about your client and server code. The exception is rather generic.

Comment: OK, I re-factored code in AuthenticationService, and now I don't get this exception, however the loading indicator doesn't stop spinning, app. is not loaded.

Comment: I'm afraid my psychic abilities aren't what they used to be... *"I see a flawed config file... on the left.. up a bit... yes there!"*. We can't just guess what code you re-factored and what it is doing. Client code? Server code? Config files? Anything?

Comment: The problem is not with the line of code shown, it probably lies with the MainPageViewModel object you are binding and the bindings themselves. Most likely a data connection issue, but there is not enough code to say where.